# SqlTrackingService 4.0 not tracking workflow instances created in 3.5 Framework

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

We have a few workflows developed under the 3.5 framework. We use tracking in it works just fine.
We are trying to change our code's build to the 4.0 framework and we didn't have problems with that. The workflows were converted as is.

When creating a new workflow after the moving to 4.0 and tracking it, it works fine.
But when trying to continue a workflow instance that was previously created with the 3.5 build of the application, the workflow runs as expected but the SqlTrackingService does not write tracking data.

I tried to debug the assembly and I noticed the the runtime does not see that there is a tracking service associated or cannot find the tracking profile.

I noticed that a new type was added to the [Type] table for the SqlTrackingService with the 4.0.0.0 version.

Did anyone run into this situation where you need to move to the 4.0 framework bu still continue old workflows ?

Comment: Hello. Did you ever get a resolution to this problem?

Comment: No. I solved it by keeping an old version of the application (still under 3.5) and using it to complete the old ones. Of course this doesn't work if the there were siginificant changes in your code/DB.

Answer (score 0):

you can Workflow tracking migration document.
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8349

And migratin process.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff637729(v=azure.10).aspx

Comment: Thanks. I checked these links but I don't think they address the problem. The first link describes how to change the WF code to the 4.0 namespaces. The second one assumes that recompiling the code in the the 4.0 framework will just work.  As I mentioned before, workflow instances created (The same worfklow types we used before) are tracked correctly, but instances created in the 3.5 version are not tracked when continuing them on the 4.0 runtime